# Fiware Cosmos. Difficulties accessing my own cosmos content

Tags: fiware-cosmos

I have problems accessing my own content in cosmos.

For example I can't change perms

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R a+rwx /user/[myuser]/[myfolder]

changing permissions of 'hdfs://cosmosmaster-gi/[myuser]/[myfolder]/by_year=2015/by_week=27/000000_0':org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied
```

Or if I try to delete a folder

```
hadoop fs -rmr /user/[myuser]/[myfolder]

rmr: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=myuser, access=ALL, inode="/user/[myuser]/[myfolder] /by_year=2015":root:myuser:drwxr-xr-x
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be currentely fixed after upgrading the global instance of Cosmos to HiveServer2, which uses the "doAs" functionality.